# Query saved data in iPhone program

Tags: iphone, sql, core-data

I have a small program which saves data to tables using CoreData. Is there a quick way or tool to search through the saved data ? A visual tool (such as Toad or Oracle sqlPlus) would be best. Any pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

Any of the standard SQL tools will let you look at a Core Data SQL store. The command line `sqlite3` should get you in.

If you want a Core Data specific version, look at [Core Data Editor](http://christian-kienle.de/CoreDataEditor/).